# Loading data to Big Query from Local Database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am wanting to start a data warehouse in Google Big Query but I'm not sure how to actually schedule jobs to get the data into the cloud.

To give some background.
I have a MySQL database hosted on-prem which I currently take a demp of each night as a backup. My idea is that I can send this dump to the Google Cloud and have it import the data into Big Query.
I have thought that I could send the dump and probably use a cloud scheduler function to then run something that opens the dump and does this but I'm unsure how these services all fit together.

I'm a bit of a newby with the Google Cloud so if there is a better way to achieve this then I'm happy to change my plan of action.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you will need to create a Cloud Storage bucket running
`gsutil mb gs://BUCKET_NAME`.

After creating the bucket you need to create a cloud function triggered by the bucket using the finalize option.

You can follow this sample function

```
'use strict';

const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

// Instantiates a client
const storage = Storage();
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

/**
 * Creates a BigQuery load job to load a file from Cloud Storage and write the data into BigQuery.
 *
 * @param {object} data The event payload.
 * @param {object} context The event metadata.
 */
exports.loadFile = (data, context) => {
    const datasetId = 'Your_Dataset_name';
    const tableId = 'Your_Table_ID';

    const jobMetadata = {
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND'
    };

    // Loads data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
    bigquery
        .dataset(datasetId)
        .table(tableId)
        .load(storage.bucket(data.bucket).file(data.name), jobMetadata)
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });

    console.log(`Loading from gs://${data.bucket}/${data.name} into ${datasetId}.${tableId}`);
};
```

Then create your BigQuery dataset using your desired schema

And now you can upload your csv file into your bucket and you will see the uploaded data in your bigquery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I think I'll give this a go as it looks like I could use this for other forms of data not just MySQL which would be really helpful. Thanks, I'll give it a go and probably come back and ask more questions haha

Answer (score 1):

As the new EXTERNAL_QUERY has been launched and you can query from BigQuery a Cloud SQL instance, your best shot right now is:

1. Setup replica from your current instance to a Cloud SQL instance, follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external).
2. Understand how [Cloud SQL federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) let's you query from BigQuery Cloud SQL instances.

You get this way a live access to your relational database as:

Example query that you run on BigQuery:

```
SELECT * EXTERNAL_QUERY(
'connection_id',
'''SELECT * FROM mysqltable AS c ORDER BY c.customer_id'');
```

You can even join Bigquery table with SQL table:

Example:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, SUM(t.amount) AS total_revenue,
rq.first_order_date
FROM customers AS c
INNER JOIN transaction_fact AS t ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN EXTERNAL_QUERY(
  'connection_id',
  '''SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS first_order_date
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY customer_id''') AS rq ON rq.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.name, rq.first_order_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like this is probably the cleanest way of doing what I want given that in the future, the on prem db will probably be hosted in the cloud anyway. I'll give this a go!